# Domain Entities. I Do Not Understand What Is Persisted By The Infrastructure Layer

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I am trying to understand Domain Driven Design. My Domain has an entity.

```
    public class Person
    {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
       public void DoSomethingInterestingToThisPerson() { }
       //etc
    }
```

In the application project I have a PersonDTO used for the UI project.

```
        public class PersonDTO
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public int Age { get; set; }
        }
```

The UI & the data project reference the Application. The application references the Domain project. What gets persisted in the database? Is it the PersonDTO? How do I query the db for people if the db does not "know" about the Person object?

Comment: The db absolutely knows about Person but after getting data from your query you have to Map to Dto and send it for clients.

Comment: Ok obviously that makes sense. It was just that I had seen tutorials where they stated that the infrastructure did not reference the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your domain should exactly match the table, you can use `AutoMapper` to map `DTO` and `Entity` for to and from `DB` operations, can you not simply do this with `EntityFramework` and `AutoMapper`?

Comment: I didn't think the infrastructure project was supposed to reference the domain model. That was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I quite disagree with @Aadittya.

First of all, DDD usualy goes with Hexagonal Architecture (further HA, or Onion Arch, Clean Arch - CA, ...).

Lets take a short look at HA.
HA is pretty simple architecture, some ppl say it has evolved from Layered Architecture, idk, its possible. The most important thing about HA is it heavily depends on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle. Main layer is the domain one. This layer contains business rules made by domain entities and services.

The most simple example can be User entity with UserRepository. UserRepository usually works with database, but database is implementation detail which does not belong to domain layer (we will take a look at it later), so we make UserRepository as an interface with necessary methods. Lets ignore exact definitions of repository patterns - there is few of them, and lets just put all storage related methods here - lets go with methods getById, save and findByUsername.

Now its good practice to have an entrypoint to your application, it can be application service, or Use Cases defined by Uncle Bob, or even commands and queries defined by CQRS. Lets stick with Use Cases here. Now lets say we want to create new User. So we create a Use Case called CreateUserUseCase. Now we have domain entity User, domain service (or interface, we shouldnt care) UserRepository which offers us method findByUsername to find an user and method save to save user. Use Casees should have some input DTO, I like to name it UseCaseName+Request (in my current company we use Input instead of Request suffix). This contains all required values, so lets say username and password. In our CreateUserUseCase we try to fetch user with method findByUsername from our UserRepository, if it returns an user, we throw an exception UsernameExistsException, or smth, if null, we map our CreateUserUseCaseRequest to User domain and we pass it to save method on UserRepository.

Now we need an implementation of UserRepository, we need to pus somewhere HibernateUserRepository implementation of our UserRepository interface. There is Infrastructure layer which is ment for implementation details like database entities and repositoreis (finders,..), or http repositories, or controllers (or any other http handlers). So we put our HibernateUserRepository to Infrastructure\Hibernate\Repositories and our database entity to Infrastructure\Hibernate\Entities. As HibernateUserRepository implements UserRepository, it works with domain entity User. That all methods accepting User entity, is User from domain entity, and when it returns User, it returns User entity again from domain layer, but internaly uses its Hibernate entities. That means you probably want to introduce mapping method in the repository implementation, or even mapper somewhere in the specific implementation detail namespace.

But this can be a lot of work, so there are tools which try to automate that. But as mentioned before, you model your domain and then you model your database according to your domain model. Domain should not follow database schema.

It comes with some benefits. You can delay deciding what database you want to use and use inmemory implementation for development in the meantime (and in unit tests you actually go with inmemory implementation). And actually you should delay making decision of implementation details according to Uncle Bob.

I believe this https://youtu.be/5_un3PUER8U?si=QnE-FAaW55FtHQGs&t=1012 is using some tool to map aggregates (dont bother with aggregates so far, think of them as domain entities, but it is nice DDD pattern tho) to relational database.

One more thing about the video, the guy puts his mapping to SomeApp\Infrastructure\Persistance. I prefer to name this namespace after library im using, or database (i dont rly use multiple libraries to work with one database), because there is one more think. As I wrote before about "multiple repository definitions", there is one which sais repository should have only two metohds - getById and save. You usually want to be able to find data by some other property than id, and this is done using finders. Its good practice to have one finder per specific query. Why? Because you can decide your MSSQL database is nice as a source of truth, but slow for some queries. When you have your SuperSlowQueryFinder separated from repository and other finders, you can make implementation for different database which suits this case more. You have to deal with synchronizing data, which is a trade off which can pay off, or not.

I hope my reply makes sence, I tried to read it couple of times and it does to me, but I wrote, so who knows.

I could go deeper in HA, but I believe I already wrote a lot of lines which are not direct answer.

In case you are interested more in HA, I can recommend not using Ports and Adapters in naming convention (port is interface in your domain layer which has "driven adapter(s)" - implementation(s) - for specific technology; driving adapter is for example Controller which calls your UseCase). I recommend to use Uncles Bob naming convention from his CA, which is basicly the same. People tend to have Ports namespace in Domain, or as a separate layer, which IMO makes the code scattered way too much in your project without any benefit. I find possibility to find all ports at one place useless, Ive never needed it.

More about [Hexagonal Architecture](https://netflixtechblog.com/ready-for-changes-with-hexagonal-architecture-b315ec967749) and [Clean Architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html).

I would avoid DDD until you understand HA/CA as DDD is not just programming, it consists from strategy patterns (code) and tactical patterns (modeling processes). But I definitelly recommend to learn DDD, when you understand HA/CA.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, your Entity should have an ID. Otherwise it would be a Value Object, which has completely different constraints. But that's not your case, since you're trying to model a person. And as such, that person should be considered as unique in your system (as we all are :) ) and therefore have an ID.
That is your first step.
Now, that ID can be a GUID, an int, a long. I'd personally go for a GUID, since you can generate them on the client, before sending the Entity to the DB.

And here we go to the juicy part: what you would be persisting is a database-specific representation of your Entity.

Let me put it this way: your Domain project contains the Entities. It should also contain the **interfaces** to operate with the persistence layer.
Bear in mind that I wrote **interfaces**, because the actual implementations should go in a separate project.

The Persistence project would reference the Domain one and contain all the necessary code to write/read (and potentially map) those Domain Entities to whatever DB you've picked. It might even be possible that no mapping is needed. I've seen that happening with EntityFramework, although some additional configuration per Entity is necessary.